# how to delete empty spaces in string in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my app.js method to call

```
const charText = this.state.userInput.trim().split('').map(ch=>{
        return <CharText text={ch.replace(/ /g, "")}/>
    })
```

my CharText.js file method

```
const charText = (props) =>{
return (
    <div className="charText">
        {props.text.toUpperCase()}
    </div>
    );
}
export default charText;
```

but still am unable to delete white spaces from the string
screenshot attached below
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzIgs.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const charText = this.state.userInput.replace(/ /g, "").split('').map(ch=>{
  return <CharText text={ch}/>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

String.prototype.trim() will only remove white space from each end of the string.

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to remove white spaces from the ends and the middle.

```
const charTextArray = this.state.userInput.split('').filter(ch=>{
        ch !== ' '
    })
return charTextArray.join('')
```

As mentioned above, you can use the `String.prototype.replace()` method as well to avoid converting to an array.

Answer (score 0):

### Use If statement

If I get you correctly you Don't want to return `div` if there is a space.

add if statement `if(!string) return null;`

```
const charText = (props) =>{
if(!props.text) return null;
return (
    <div className="charText">
        {props.text.toUpperCase()}
    </div>
    );
}
export default charText;
```

BTW this also good:

```
string.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

and there is empty unicode: "⠀" (between the quotation marks is the unicode).